# GET https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: jquery, cdn

My html uses "jquery.min.js"  by https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>xxxx</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Today it suddenly doesn't work, chrome console show:

```
GET https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

What should i do for the url? Can i change another one? Or download jquery.js(3.4.1) and put it on my service? This web only services for about 1000 people.

Comment: *What should i do for the url?* change it to one that doesn't give a 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We download this file from other [source](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js), deploy it to our server.
And change the  `<script src="xxxx"` address to our domain.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33083774)